# What's it called when someone tries to stop you from doing something by telling you you to do it?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Sometimes when someone tells you to do something in a sarcastic but serious way so that you do not do it like: “yeah, go to the party on your own — maybe you’ll get hit by a car on your way back.”

Is there a word to describe this kind of speech or maybe there is a specific word you use to call the person who talks like this?

Comment: They are *daring* you, using sarcasm.

Comment: Sarcasm is usually defined as the use of verbal irony (usually antiphrasis) in a biting way.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **calling someone's bluff.**

> Challenge someone to carry out a stated intention, in the expectation of being able to expose it as a pretence.

*She was tempted to call his bluff, hardly believing he'd carry out his threat.*

[Lexico]